# How to Enable the display?

Tags: java, colors

How to do setting:

1. Enable the display of   < and > (that you use in your Java source codes) as   < and > respectively, not as a white space ' ', < and >;
2. Color String literals in String markers "..." with gray and ensure double slashes "//" in any String literal to have the right color gray, not green;
3. Color comment blocks in between /* ... */ with green.

   ```
    import java.io.*; 

    class java2colorHTML { 

    public static String [] modifiers = {"class", "public", "private", "static", "void", "int", "long", }; 
    public static String [] other_keywords  = {"import", "throws", "new", "null", "true", "false", "for", "while", "do", "if", "else", "break", "return", "continue",}; // still need to collect many many more

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException { 
    // running: java java2colorHTML <fn.java>

    String txt = myIO.readFile(args[0]); 

        txt = txt.replace("<", "&lt;");
        txt = txt.replace(">", "&gt;"); // need to be done before "<br>" gets in!        
        txt = txt.replace("\r\n|\n", "<br>"); // line break        
        txt = txt.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
        txt = txt.replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"); // unicode '\u0009' for tab

        for (String w : modifiers) { 
            txt = txt.replaceAll(w + "&nbsp;", "<font color=\"#aa33ff\">" + w + "</font>&nbsp;");
            // txt = txt.replaceAll(" " +w, "<font color=\"#9933ee\"> " + w + "</font>");
        }
        for (String w : other_keywords) {
            txt = txt.replaceAll(w + "&nbsp;", "<font color=\"#3333ff\">" + w + "</font>&nbsp;");
            txt = txt.replaceAll("&nbsp;" + w, "&nbsp;<font color=\"#3333ff\">" + w + "</font>");
            txt = txt.replaceAll("\\(" + w + "\\)", "(<font color=\"#3333ff\">" + w + "</font>)");
        }

        int bgn = 0;
        while (true) { // colour comment lines, if any
            bgn = txt.indexOf("\"", bgn == 0 ? 0 : bgn+1); // get next bgn
            if (bgn == -1) break; // if no more literal strings
            int end = txt.indexOf("\"", bgn+1); //find line break after bgn

            String str_Literals = txt.substring(bgn+1, end); // get current literal strings quote to the end
            str_Literals = str_Literals.replaceAll("</*[^<>]+>", ""); // remove embedded font tags, if any
            str_Literals = "<font color= \"#a3a3a3\">" + str_Literals + "</font>"; // coloring the literals
            txt = txt.substring(0, bgn) + str_Literals + 
                  txt.substring(end);
            bgn += str_Literals.length(); // set bgn to the end of current literals
                                          // avoid a bug here, because txt has been changed!

        }


        bgn = 0;
        while (true) { // color comment lines, if any
            bgn = txt.indexOf("//", bgn == 0 ? 0 : bgn+1); // get next bgn
            if (bgn == -1) break; // if no more comment
            int end = txt.indexOf("<br>", bgn); // find line break after bgn
            String comment = txt.substring(bgn, end); // get current comment
            comment = comment.replaceAll("</*[^<>]+>", ""); // remove embedded font tags, if any
            comment = "<font color=\"#009900\">" + comment + "</font>"; // coloring a comment
            txt = txt.substring(0, bgn) + comment +
                  txt.substring(end);
            bgn += comment.length(); // set bgn to the end of current comment
                                     // avoid a bug here, because txt has been changed!
        }

        System.out.println("<html>\r\n<body>\r\n<tt>\r\n");
        System.out.println(txt);
        System.out.println("\r\n</tt>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>");

    }
   }
   ```

Comment: You have told us what your requirements are, and you have shown your code.  That’s good.  Now we just need to know what problem you’re having with it.  What result did you expect?  What result are you seeing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the question is in the title, how to display your nice HTML.

Instead of

```
 System.out.println("<html>\r\n<body>\r\n<tt>\r\n");
 System.out.println(txt);
 System.out.println("\r\n</tt>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>");
```

Make txt the complete HTML content.

```
 txt = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/></head>\r\n"
     + "<body>\r\n<tt>\r\n" 
     + txt + "\r\n</tt>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>";
```

I added the charset UTF-8.

Then save the HTML:

```
Path htmlPath = Paths.get(args[0] + ".html"); // Or a temporary file:
Path htmlPath = Files.createTempFile("nice-", ".html");
Files.writeString(htmlPath, txt);
```

Now let the operating system open (display) it:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlPath.toUri());
```

Comment: I want to know how to change the font color assignment of the picture. Could you please tell me?
https://upload.cc/i1/2021/10/20/QuTXha.jpg

Comment: Try `<span style="color:#3333ff; font-family:Cambria,Sans-Serif">...</span>`

Comment: Why is the MAC computer unable to execute the following JAVA code? The color displayed on the web page is wrong!

upload.cc/i1/2021/10/20/QuTXha.jpg

https://pasteboard.co/tSBOkkZUrS09.jpg

Comment: There is a bug `txt = txt.replace("\r\n|\n", "<br>"); // line break` intended to use `replaceAll` (regex). But the code considers a kind of half existing html tags. Best you look in the browser (devtools often F12) and try out what might be the problem.

Comment: `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` should be `<meta charset=\"UTF-8"\>` or `<meta charset='UTF-8'>`.

Comment: @VGR thanks, second backslash should also be before the double quotes.

Comment: @Joop Eggen How to write the internal code, there will be no bugs. Like the picture below, the color is displayed on the webpage. I can't find the correct way to write it!
https://upload.cc/i1/2021/10/20/QuTXha.jpg

Comment: Looks real good code. You could try **web color names** instead of hex codes. They are standard. Teal, olive green etc. I have even seen a site converting hex codes to the nearest named color

Comment: I want this JAVA internal code to be displayed on the webpage with colors displayed on the HTML website!
upload.cc/i1/2021/10/20/QuTXha.jpg

Comment: Sorry, can't help you further.